# Link to child to parent in Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a Place Model:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=REGION, null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_('date created'), default=timezone.now)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(_('date_modified'), auto_now=True)
```

Originally I create place to save information about a city, like San Francisco or New York.

Now I want to create a new model called Bar:

```
class Bar(Place):
    location = models.OneToOneField(Place, verbose_name=_('location'), related_name='bar', blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, parent_link=True)
    date_inception = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_closed = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to link the bar to a particular city in the Place model. So I'm linking one row of the an inherited model with its parent. Can I avoid creating a city model and the Bar should Foreignkey into? Is this doable? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: The Bar is already linked to a city.  You can simply call `Bar.city`.  What are you trying to accomplish by *"linking Bar to a particular city"*?

Comment: @CalebGoodman I deleted the city field to avoid confusion. To clarify, I create a Place called 'San Francisco'. Then I create a Bar called 'Blackbird'. I want to be able to link Blackbird to San Francisco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `parent_link=True` in your `OneToOneField`, the joined models are treated as *the same model* when working with the ORM, even though they are two separate database tables.

There is no need to link `Bar` to a particular `Place`;  you can use the `Bar` model to create both the `Bar` instance and the `Place` instance at the same time:

```
bar = Bar.objects.create(name='Blackbird', city='San Fransisco', 
          country='US', date_inception='10-17-2019', ...
      )
```

Based on your comments, I'm guessing you don't want this at all.  Instead, you probably want a `ForeignKey` relationship between `Place` and the `Bar` model, since a *place* (eg San Fransisco) can have many bars, but a bar can only have *one place*.

### Update

From my understanding of your comments, this is what I would suggest:

```
class PlaceMixin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        latitude = self.latitude
        longitude = self.longitude
        do_stuff(latitude, longitude)
        super().save()

class Location(PlaceMixin):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=REGION, null=True, blank=True)

class Bar(PlaceMixin):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='bars', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Store(PlaceMixin):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='stores', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now you can access both the lat/long of the `Place`, and of the `Location`:

```
>>>location = Location.objects.create(name='San Fransisco', latitude=1, longitude=1)
>>>bar = Bar.objects.create(name='Blackbird', latitude=2, longitude=2, location=location)
>>>
>>>bar.latitude
2
>>>bar.location.latitude
1
```

To query all bars in San Fransisco:

```
location = Location.objects.select_related('Bar').get(name='San Fransisco')
bars = location.bars.all()
```

Comment: Then I can't have Bar inherit from Place then?

Comment: @HC It depends on what you want your `Place` model to accomplish.

Comment: The reason I wanted Bar to inherit from Place is because it has 90% of the fields I need. But I want the longitude and latitude of both the Place and the Bar.

Comment: what do you mean by *"I want the longitude and latitude of both the Place and the Bar"*?  It sounds like you want an [abstract model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Comment: I want to be able to query Bar.longitude (Blackbird, which I can do by inheriting from Place) and at the same time call Bar.location(which is Place).longitude (San Francisco). I would like to link the city that the bar is in into another object which is Place/City that has already been created. Both should be concrete.

Comment: So I really I have to create a City model (what I call Place right now) even though, Bar and City might have almost the exact same fields.

Comment: as you mentioned, I would like to query all of the bars in San Francisco. Having to create almost duplicate model seems wasteful. I'm just seeing if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: @HC you are right, see my update.  With this change you can access *all* duplicate fields (postal_code, country, etc) in both your `Location` and in `Bar` without having to duplicate the fields.

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: quick question how do you do this with an abstract model?  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  try:
   place = PlaceMixin.objects.get(id_google=self.id_google)

  except PlaceMixin.DoesNotExist:

Comment: @HC AFAIK, you can't.  abstract models are only for inheriting fields shared among multiple models.  You'd need to call `bar = Bar.objects.get(...)`.

Comment: so then I would have to replicate this method in all of the concrete model that inherits from PlaceMixin?

Comment: Why do you need to call `PlaceMixin.objects.get` inside of a `save` method?

Comment: I automatically call Google Map to grab the longitude and latitude when saving the object.

Comment: No need to query anything.  You can access `latitude` and `longitude` directly via `self`.  See my update

Comment: But you only want to grab the data from the api if the object doesn't already exist. That's where the Try and except come in. But since it's abstract, the object in PlaceMixin technically doesn't exist. So I think I might have to move it into the concrete models?

Comment: Nope.  `self` references the instance that the method is called from, not the class object itself.

Comment: How do you check if the instance exist first before calling the api to populate the information?